# importing angular 2 components run time from external application or as files

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, custom-component

my application have capability of dynamically loading components to the UI based on user input.now have a requirement of loading external components to our application run time in case if client want any customized component to render his data.
i would like to know is there any way to load angular 2 components run time to application which is not imported to app.module.ts as declaration.
any help any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: yes, you need to load and compile the module. see [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e)

Comment: it was really helpful thank you so much, i would request you to provide a sample code or Plunker for  section ' Creating components on the fly'

Comment: what exactly is not clear in the article?

Comment: i have already wrote a framework which will load components dynamically with componentfactoryresolver  were in this case i declared my components in a shared module as entrycomponents each of this components can have mulitiple inputs and outputs ,all of em will trigger ngOnChanges on demand. 
now  I want to know if i create an angular module programmatic way and loading components from there will it work in the same way or i should do any other changes on my existing framework. if you just provide a sample code i can experiment with that.

Comment: there's a working github repo in the article I mentioned, here [is the link](https://github.com/maximusk/Here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-Angular)

Comment: thanks alot... :D cheers